# Is the xor of a prg and a function still a prg?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, xor

I have this couple of deterministic functions $G_1$ and $G_2$. Suppose at least I of them is a PRG. Take $G^*=G_1(x)$ xor $G_2(x)$ with the same $x$. I have to show whether this is still a PRG. I thought about this counterexample: if $G_1=G_2$ then $G^*$ cannot be a PRG but my teacher said then $G^*$ isn't interesting.

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe you should ask your teacher what your teacher means by "interesting".

Comment: If the teacher asked the question in these terms and did not accept this perfectly valid counterexample, changing teacher might be the best option. On the other hand, it's quite possible that a part of the puzzle is missing or distorted.

Answer (score -2):

Take 2 bits $x1$ & $x2$ generateD by $G_1$ & $G_2$ respectively. Let $G_2$ be a good PRG i.e $x2$ generated by $G_2$ is perfectly random. So there is 50% probability that $x2$ is $0$ or $1$. Let $G_1$ be a terrible PRG - i.e. it always generates the same value.

Truth table of $x1$ XOR $x2$

| x1 | x2 | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

Even with a fixed $x1$ (i.e. $x1$ is always 1), the output after XOR with a perfectly Random $x2$ has 50% probability of being 0 or 1. i.e. $G_1$ $XOR$ $G_2$ is a PRG.

---

More formal Proof

Let's have a biased $a$ and a perfectly unbiased $b$:

$P(a = 0) = x$

$P(a = 1) = 1 - x$

$P(b = 0) = 0.5$

$P(b = 1) = 0.5$

$P(a\text{ XOR } b = 0) = $

$= P(a = 0) * P(b = 0) + P(a = 1) * P(b = 1) =$

$= x * 0.5 + (1 - x) * 0.5$

$= 0.5x + 0.5 - 0.5x$

$= 0.5$

$P(a \text { XOR } b = 1)$

$= P(a = 1) * P(b = 0) + P(a = 0) * P(b = 1) $

$= (1 - x) * 0.5 + x * 0.5$

$= 0.5 - 0.5x + 0.5x $

$    = 0.5$

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't see your point, this seems to me just an example where $G^*$ is a PRG and not a proof it is always.

Comment: @Cristie - see the proof after the example. `The function generating `a` is not fixed like in the example. The bias is variable - i.e. `x`. Irrespective of what value `x` is, the output is unbiased

Comment: This is not correct since the output sequences are not independent.